# Xamarin forms Can't Access Camera

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My cross platform mobile app is taking photo with this codes

```
public void TakePhoto()
        {
            Context context = MainActivity.Instance;
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            AppCamera._file = new Java.IO.File(AppCamera._dir, String.Format("Photo_{0}.jpg", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyhhmmss")));
            intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(AppCamera._file));
            activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
```

I have the app on Android version 4.4 to 7.0 platforms and it works fine.
but it is not working on a google pixel phone which Android version is 8.1.

Note: Calling this function using dependency service.

```
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<ICameraProvider>();
DependencyService.Get<ICameraProvider>().TakePhoto()
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin Forms. and my project build properties platform target is Latest Platform Android 8.1(Oreo).

Any idea what the problem is ?

Comment: How are you asking for permissions?

Comment: yes, Permission are set.. for Read/write and camera

Comment: Remember that in Android 6.0+ you need to proactively ask for permissions, manifest permissions are just for reference and they are NOT granted by default during installation.

Comment: upon install the app it is not asking for any permission. 
and I am setting the permissions after install, from Setting -> applications-> myapp->Permissions.

Comment: Set target version to override 23 in android mainifest.

Comment: I have Set target version to override 23 in android manifests and it works but I do not understand why it worked @Yogesh
because I am testing it to 27

Comment: @Ronjon You have to ask the user for permission: https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Answer (score 1):

> Xamarin forms Can't Access Camera

As Jesus Angulo and SushiHangover said, the permission need request the user to approve at runtime on Android 6.0 and higher. This is [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for requesting runtime permissions. You could also refer to this [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) and this [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-m/RuntimePermissions/) for request runtime permission in xamarin.

Here is a simple demo:

```
        public void TakePhoto()
        {
            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                var requiredPermissions = new String[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera };
                var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, requiredPermissions, 100);
            }    
            while (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                 //waiting user permission
            }    

            //Other code   
            //...
            //... 
        }
```

And you also need set permission in AndroidManifest.xml or it will automatically be denied.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```